# What is the simplest way to get datagrid foreground change in C#?

Tags: c#, datagrid, foreground

I am trying to change the foreground color of all the contents of my datagrid upon chosing a radio button (using C# in VS2010 / .Net 4.0).

I was able to successfully get the background image to change upon radio button selection, and I thought the datagrid foreground color would be just as easy. However,5 hours of research, rewriting code and testing yeilds nothing.

Is it more complicated? Or Is it just a matter or adding something like either of the following into a radio button event? I've tried these with no luck...

```
         dataGrid1.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```

### **or**

```
        var dg = new DataGrid();
        dg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: DataGridView has a ForeColorChanged event.  Not DataGrid.  Did California disappear in the ocean to consider red for *every* cell?  If it did, do consider up-lifting your control.

Comment: What is your application type... Win form, WPF ? Win form contains DataGridView.

Comment: It's WPF. I'm a newbie to both .Net and C#.

Comment: OK... I've figured out how to link it to the radio button via Style and Data triggers. For anyone seeking the same... here is what I used:  
`code` <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle> <Style> <Style.Triggers><DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioButton1}" Value="True" >
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>

                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle> `code`